# Azure logic App CTLR+V function no longer working

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a working logic app that triggers an Outlook365 email v3 with options action.  I have the body of the email in html code and it has been working very well.  However I have been asked to update the email body and have to change the code..........no problem fix the html and past it back in right?........not.

The paste function is not working on the portal or in visual studio for the body element.  I can type in manually type into it but no pasting as I did on the original action......any ideas as to what is going on?

copy/paste works on all desktop applications (word,notepad....) just not in the logic app design window.

highlighted email body in html was pasted into this field......it will not allow it to be updated via pasting an update code set.

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXrrh.png)

Comment: Could you please provide more details such as screenshots of your work flow ?

Comment: I test it in my side but I can't reproduce this problem. It seems the problem may be caused by your system, could you please refresh the logic app or restart your computer and then test again ?

Answer (score 0):

It's strange and I can't reproduce the problem in my side. I guess the problem may be caused by system. You can try to refresh the logic app page or restart the computer and then try the ctrl+V operation.

If still same problem, you can paste the html code to a variable(if you can paste the code to the variable value).

[image]

And then use the variable in the body of send email.

[image]